# NextJS portal, my console returns "Target container is not a DOM element nextjs", how it is possible since I have well defined it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to put a portal in NextJS
I have well defined its related div, here my _document.js:

```
<html> 
...
<div id='portal'/> 
<NextScript />
 </body> 
</html>
```

I then call the div inside my PortalComponent:

```
export default class Portal extends React.Component {
 componentDidMount(){ 
   this.modalRoot = document.getElementById('portal');
}
```

But it returns me null, how it is possible since I have put my div#portal in _document.js ? I also wait for document to be accessible ... so I'm a little surprised by theses results,
I have assumed maybe the div's name is hashed but in this case how retrieve the hash name? I'm not sure is that maybe it's a just a tiny setting option to tweak.

Any hint would be great
thanks

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/FAQ#i-use-a-library-which-throws-window-is-undefined will help

Comment: thanks it helps improve my code but still returns null :/

Comment: Aah I have forgot to  restart my server xp.

Comment: The link above doesn't exist anymore. If a proper answer were written, and the content of the link copied to it, this could solve problems until today.